# rename file problem under subversion

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem when I rename the checked out working file from Tortorise under subversion.  After rename the local file, my local file got lost.  I want to know how I can get my local copy back, either from Tortorise or other?

Comment: Your description is a little unclear. Can you describe the steps you performed and the odd behavior you saw afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "svn add path/to/your/local/file"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using a Tortoise to check out my code from Subversion. The file name on repository is changed, I want to update my local file, so I use Tortoise to rename my local copy to match the name on repository, but the local file is gone.  I want to know how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the file name was changed on the server then you just need to update to get the latest version, the old name problably will remain but just delete it.
If you haven´t committed the changes on your WC then just do a revert to undo all changes done on your side and then update the folder.